# Is it possible to deploy a django project to heroku without putting the project in git?

Tags: django, git, heroku

I was wondering if it is possible to deploy to heroku with out putting my django project on git?

My another question. I already have my app on heroku. Now I want to make changes to it. But the computer I had the soruce code crashed. So how do I download my project files from heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. ( But there is a plugin to do that, but I would say why bother. But.. - https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push)

But all you have to do is `git init` to setup a repo, and push to the heroku remote after setting up an app. You don't have to publish your repo anywhere.

You can get back your code by using:

```
heroku clone <appname>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there a way to download my existing project files?

Comment: what is the difference between heroku clone and git clone? I apologize if the question is to basic to ask. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @pradeepreddy - It is an helper provided by the heroku plugin. It effectively does `git clone`.